# What does the phrase to post imply?

Tags: word-meaning

> Having written the letter, she hurried to the post-office to post it.

I do not quite understand the sentence clearly.   Which of the three below is correct?

> 1. she hurried to the post office and then she actually posted it.
> 2. she hurried to the post office in order for her to post it.
> 3. it depends on the context.

Could you help me clarify it?  Thanks.

Comment: As with your other questions today,  checking an English learners dictionary might answer your question:  [**to post**](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/post) (v): *3. to send (a letter or package) by mail*.   You can *post* mail at the *post office*.

Comment: "did *verb* to *other-verb*" almost always means "for the purpose of *other-verbing*".

Comment: *I **hesitate to correct** you, but 'fu-bar' is not a snack to eat on a hike.*  *The ardent fan **dared to get** a tattoo of an eagle on her left buttock.*

Answer (score 1):

If all we are told is that single sentence then any reader would assume that she did indeed post the letter: your (1). But that sentence would be consistent with the meaning of your (2) (but you do not need "for her") if the next sentence said something like "But she met Mrs Jones, and, talking to her, she forgot to post it".